# Convert a video file to an image sequence of equal length?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, nuke

How using FFMPEG do I convert a video file to a sequence of images that is equal in duration/frames to the original video file?

I'm trying to import video into the non comercial version of Nuke on Linux which refuses to accept h.264 and doesn't have handy a list of accepted codecs that I can find...but plays nice with images sequences...but I can't get the sound to line up with the image sequence.

I tried getting a look at the framerate with:

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0 -select_streams 0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate Forest.mp4
```

which returns:

```
r_frame_rate=30/1
```

and then I run

```
ffmpeg -i Forest.mp4 -r 30/1 forest/jpegs%06d.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your video is constant frame rate (avg_frame_rate should be same as r_frame_rate),

use

```
ffmpeg -i Forest.mp4 -vsync 0 forest/jpegs%06d.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-commercial version of NUKE is functionally limited:

- Output resolution is limited to FullHD (1920 x 1080).
- 2D format support is disabled for MPEG4 and H264.
- etc...

So you should go this way to make image sequence:

```
ffmpeg -i Forest.mp4 image%04d.tif
```

Comment: I don't see a reason to do 2 passes when a single pass with `-crf` should suffice.

Comment: I don't see a reason to do any transcoding if the app accepts MP4s.

Comment: @Mulvya There are two reasons why MP4 is bad for Nuke: it's 8bit per channel (not good for CC and grading) and mp4 video is slower than image sequence when playing back and compositing.

Comment: Ok, but the OP already has a H.264 stream. Unless libx264 was set to 10-bit during compile, your command is transcoding to another 8-bit H.264 stream (forced to 2 mbps). That's one generation loss added. The container (MP4) doesn't really matter.